# How to bind a list of strings to a datalist id in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, controller, datalist

How do I bind a List to a datalist id. The List is in a controller class and the datalist id is in a view(chtml file)?

I tried using this datalist id in the controller class, but I get the error "The name "id(some id name)" does not exist in the current context".

See code bellow:

```html
<input list="cardProgram" class="form-control input-group-lg">
    <asp:DataList id="cardProgram" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <%# Eval("Value") %>>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    BindCardPrograms();
}

private async void BindCardPrograms()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59066/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ViewBag.country = "";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await 
            client.GetAsync("api/Profile/InitializeCardProgramSelection");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            List<String> cardPrograms = 
                response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<String>>().Result;
            cardProgram.DataSource = cardPrograms;
            cardProgram.DataBind();
        }
        /*else
        {
            return View();
         }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you wanted to display repeated element with same style but just different value ? and use the id to navigate to another page base on selected id ?

Comment: @Ivan Elv,  I want to populate the datalist with options so that a user can select their option. These options are store in a list of strings, so now I want them to be available in the input list

Comment: Did you really use cshtml file ? or aspx file ? In cshtml, Using datalist is look like ```<datalist>    <option value="something"/></datalist>```

Comment: @Ivan Elv, to be more specific, The list contains  file names from the repository layer. So I want these file names to be options in my cardProgram datalist. I want a user to be able to select one file from these options. On selection of that option, I want to read that file and populate other fields  in the view with the contents of that file selected.

Comment: I used chtml, I tried <datalist> <option value="something"/></datalist>, but again I truggled populating the options. Do you have an idea of how I can do this if I go that route?

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628415/binding-data-to-html5-datalist-in-asp-net) could help if you wanted to go using <datalist> tag.

Comment: I tried it, but still throws the same error. I think the id "browsers" has no reference in Page_Load function. That is my problem, since the Page_Load and my html are in different files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownList("cardProgram", null, "--Select--", new
                       {
                           @class = "form-control input-group-lg",
                           @onChange = "return "
                       })
```

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59066/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                ViewBag.country = "";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/CardCreation/Configure");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    List<SelectListItem> cardPrograms = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<SelectListItem>>().Result;
                    ViewBag.cardProgram = cardPrograms;
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but just in case you are still or someone else is looking for solution. My solution is a simplified version of the blog post here: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/aaecb7bc-18d2-44c5-8d81-07b8cb634a0b.aspx

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CardProgram, new { @list = "CardProgramList", @autocomplete = "off" })
<datalist id="CardProgramList"></datalist>
```

Script:

```
$(() => {
    getCardPrograms();
});

function getCardPrograms() {
    var options = {};
    options.url = "/Home/GetCardProgramList";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.success = function (data) {
        for (let item of data.result) {
            $('datalist#CardProgramList').append("<option value='" + item + "'></option>");
        };
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCardProgramList()
{
    List<string> cardProgramList = dbContext.CardPrograms.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    return Json(new { result = cardProgramList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You don't need the Page_Load() method in your controller to bind items to datalist.